# Change page from an Iframe to the Main Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iframe

I'm working inside an iframe and when i finish my job I want to change page (NOT inside iframe) but out side of this iframe, in the main window.
For this I use the following Sub:

```
Public Sub ChangePage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim myNewAsp As New AspNetSqlProvider
        Dim dbHandler As New DBHandler
        Dim srvHandler As New ServerHandler
        Dim aspProvider As New MyAspNetSqlMembershipProvider
        Dim errAnswer As New Register
        Dim assit As New Assistance
        Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Nothing
        Dim message As String = Nothing
        Dim msg As String = Nothing
        Try
            Dim url As String = "/Pages/Account/Login.aspx"
            Dim postWindow As Object   ' "/Pages/Account/Assistance.aspx"
            Dim startWindow As Object   ' "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"
            Dim urlURI As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
            Dim urlPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
            Dim myServerName As String = Strings.Left(urlURI, urlURI.Length - urlPath.Length)
            url = myServerName + url
            startWindow = Me.GetType().FullName
            postWindow = Assistance.PageUrlType
            msg = "Hellow World"
            'msg = "<script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function(){  window.location.href='" + url + "';  }); </script>"
            Dim script As Type = Me.Page.GetType()  '  Assistance.PageType.BaseType 
            Dim postmsg As String = "ChangePage('" & startWindow & "', '" & postWindow & "', '" & msg & "')"
            If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "sendMessage") Then
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(script, "sendMessage", postmsg)
            End If

        Catch eq As SqlException
            srvHandler.ErrorAnswer = DBHandler.GetError(1, Nothing, Nothing, eq, Nothing)
            srvHandler.ErrorAnswer = srvHandler.ErrorAnswer & "\r\n Asp.SQLProvider.ResetPassword "
            ServerHandler._InnerError += srvHandler.ErrorAnswer
            Register.errorCall = True
            Return
        Catch Ex As Exception
            srvHandler.ErrorAnswer = DBHandler.GetError(3, Ex, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
            srvHandler.ErrorAnswer = srvHandler.ErrorAnswer & "\r\n Asp.SQLProvider.ResetPassword"
            ServerHandler._InnerError += srvHandler.ErrorAnswer
            Register.errorCall = True
            Return

        End Try
    End Sub
```

I use the following script in the Page inside the `iFrame`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ChangePage(startPage, sendPage, message) {
         var sPage = document.getElementById(startPage);
         sPage.contentWindow.postMessage(message, sendPage);
     }
    </script>
```

I also use the following script in the Page I want to change (parent Page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    function receiveMessage(event) {
        event.origin !== message;
        event.source.postMessage("'" + message + "'", event.origin);
            return;
    }
```

what I got from the above is to have the desired page (the message in the example) BUT inside of the frame.
The scrip in the Help01.aspx page is executed just fine. But in this window, and not in the parent one (Assistance,aspx)
As a result I can't get out of the iFrame (which is inside of a table).
 
Is someone to know what to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use something like [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) here. It depends on the browsers you need to support, but support is pretty good. That will let you "talk" between the main window and the iFrame.

That link will walk you through how to set it up, but the gist of it is that you'll need to attach an event listener to the main window and then post a message from the iFrame to the outer window. Then do your redirect in the outer window when the message comes in.

So where you have `Dim msg As String...` you'll want that to be some code that posts a message to the outer frame. Something like `window.postMessage(..)`

Comment: Well dear @Zero21xxx, after a long time of waiting... doing some other thing in the code I start working with your proposal. I really don't know how to do this... I mean I don't know how to implement the code for this solution. I read lost of things about it but I could not figured out what to do... Is there any possibility to give me any kind of assistance?